# Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__count' of undefined" in grid datasource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I recently updated my jQuery and Kendo UI version. Now using jQuery 1.12.13 and Kendo UI 2016.3.914 (unsure which version it corresponds to in their public website, but probably around R3 2016).

It seems either kendo or jQuery have gotten more strict about data formats. I had a kendo UI Grid with a datasource which had `type: "json"`. This worked in earlier versions but not anymore - it gave a warning:

`Unknown DataSource transport type 'json'.
Verify that registration scripts for this type are included after Kendo UI on the page.`

So I looked at the documentation and changed the type to be `odata`.
This gave an error:

`VM94003:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__count' of undefined`

Typical to Kendo UI, this error message really doesn't tell you much. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that somehow defining the type as `odata` expects that the datasource data includes information about the size of the results. I tried adding a definition in the `schema` of the grid:

```
total: function (data) {
    return data.length;
}
```

But this didn't help.

Eventually, what did help was taking off the `type` definition completely. So now my grid's datasource has no explicit `type` definition but it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

I added the following code to schema of the dataSource and got this thing to work without removing type as `odata`.

```
schema: {
         data: function(data) {
              return data.value;
         },
         total: function(data) {
              return data['odata.count'];

         }

        }
```

The solution was found in this [link](http://coderj.net/using-the-kendo-ui-grid-with-odata-on-wcf-data-services/)